# Snowflake Ruby odbc Assertion failure: GEOGRAPHY_type_unsupported

Tags: ruby, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unixodbc

Connecting snowflake to a rails application using ODBC connector as recommended :
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Ruby-Connectivity-Options-for-Snowflake

And, as the rails odbc connector is outdated and not maintained anymore,  I use a patched one :
https://github.com/Singlespot/odbc_adapter

Unfortunately, for a couple of days, I can no longer query using my active record model. I always get :

```
ODBC::Error: S1000 (6) [Snowflake][Snowflake] (6)
  Assertion failure: GEOGRAPHY_type_unsupported

from /home/gg/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/bundler/gems/odbc_adapter-44dad924c0de/lib/odbc_adapter/schema_statements.rb:63:in `fetch_all'
```

When running even `Snowflake.connection.exec('select 1')`

The Snowflake model is :

```rb
class Snowflake < ActiveRecord::Base
  connects_to database: { writing: :snowflake, reading: :snowflake }
end
```

and the database connection is :

```yaml
snowflake:
  adapter: odbc
  conn_str: "...."
```

Answer (score 1):

to close the loop: issue is handled by Snowflake Support, and seems it is caused by a bug in the Snowflake ODBC driver, triggered when there's a GEOGRAPHY type column in any of the tables in the account. Fix is underway and will be available in a future version of the Snowflake ODBC driver. Anyone interested - please follow the [ODBC release notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/client-change-log-odbc.html).

**edit @ APR30 2021**: fixed version (2.23.2) of Snowflake ODBC driver is available for download.